Notation on "sort-of" nested sums
(My question arose in the context of computing physical properties for mixtures of species, so I will ask it within this framework. I did simplify the problem, but, because I do not have a rigorous math background, I was not able to phrase the question in more general terms. Sorry for that.)
Let's say I have a property $y$ that is a function of $N$ parameters $x_n$ as $y = \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n$. Now, consider that, for a binary mixture of species $a$ and $b$, the corresponding property $y$ for the mixture is given as
\begin{equation}
y = \sum_{n_a=1}^{N_a} \sum_{n_b=1}^{N_b} x_{a,n_a} x_{b,n_b}
\end{equation}
where the subscripts $a$ and $b$ refer to the respective species.
For a mixture of three species (say $a$, $b$, and $c$), $y$ for the mixture would be
\begin{equation}
y = \sum_{n_a=1}^{N_a} \sum_{n_b=1}^{N_b} \sum_{n_c=1}^{N_c} x_{a,n_a} x_{b,n_b} x_{c,n_c}
\end{equation}
and so on and so forth.
My question is if there is a concise way to write $y$ for a mixture of an arbitrary number of components $M$. I know that within the summation I could write something like $\prod_{m=1}^{M} x_{m,n_m}$, but how could I deal with the fact that the "number" of summations depends on $M$?

Welcome . Why is the usual dots notation not sufficient for you?

Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4177982/the-notation-for-a-sum-of-many-sums

I am not sure this would work in my case (maybe it would and I just did not understand it the answer). In the linked answer, it seems that they are simply summing up several $x$ that belong to different sets. What I have in effect is a summation of the products of the permutations between all $x_{a,n_a}$, $x_{b,n_b}$, etc; therefore, I need to select $x_{a,n_a}$ from one set of values while simultaneously selecting $x_{b,n_b}$ from a different set of values, and so on for each different component.

We use $[N]:=\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ to denote the set of the first $N$ natural numbers. The sum can then be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\left(n_1,\ldots,n_k\right)\in[N_1]\times\cdots\times[N_k]}\,\prod_{j=1}^kx_{j,n_j}
\end{align*}
or using the projection map $\pi$, a bit more compactly as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{\mathbb{n}\in[N_1]\times\cdots\times[N_k]}\,\prod_{j=1}^kx_{j,\pi_j(\mathbb{n})}}
\end{align*}

Your answer seems (I think) similar to this answer suggested by Martin as a comment to my question. Please see my reply to their comment.

@GuilhermeFraga: In contrast to the referred question each summand here is a product $x_{1,n_1} x_{2,n_2}\cdots x_{k,n_k}$.

I think what you are looking for is the sum of all the elements in the Kronecker product of the vectors corresponding the lists of parameter values for each species.
For your purpose you might be best off describing that in words and an example rather than hard to parse formal sums and products with double subscripts.

Property $y$ for a set of species is the sum of the products of all combinations of the
parameters for each of the species. For example with two species $a$ and $b$ with 2 and 3 parameters respectively $y$ is the sum of the six terms $$
a(1)b(1)+a(2)b(1) + a(1)b(2)+a(2)b(2) + a(1)b(3)+a(2)b(3),
$$
or, if you prefer
$$
a_1b_1+a_2b_1 +  a_1b_2+a_2b_2 +  a_1b_3+a_2b_3.
$$

